# Android NavigationView: How to get rid of space between header and first menu item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I'm using navigation view that comes with new android support library. It works great but there is an empty space between header and first menu item in the drawer. Is it possible to get rid of this space?

[image]